# Python matplotlib giving shorter regression line

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, linear-regression

This is my current problem: sometimes, when I plot a scatter-plot and then a regression line (using the same data), the regression line calculated with `scipy.stats.linregress(y,X)` is too short, like this one:

[image: Plot screenshot]

As I already said, the data for the scatter plot and the line are the same, and usually, it works. This is the code:

```
### "results" comes from a Mysql query and passed to an np.array
Data=np.array(results)
X=Data[:,1]
y=Data[:,0]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err=linregress(y,X)
line = slope * X + intercept
plt.scatter(y, X, marker='o',color='#33ffe6',alpha=1,edgecolors='black',linewidths=0.5)
#### Plot
plt.plot(X, line, 'r', label="Regression Line", antialiased=True)
#### Label
plt.xlabel(labels[0])
plt.ylabel(labels[col])
#### scala
plt.xlim(y.min()-((y.max() / float(100)) * 5), y.max() + (y.max() / float(100)) * 5)
plt.ylim(X.min()-((X.max() / float(100)) * 5), X.max() + (X.max() / float(100)) * 5)
#### Legenda
plt.legend(loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.07), fancybox=True, shadow=True)
```

This is a drop box link with a .csv file containing the data: [here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/725d528afypmt0f/orders.csv?dl=0). The first column is the y and the second the X.

Comment: why is it plt.scatter(y, X) and plt.plot(X, plotList[index].line)? Shouldn't they both have X first?

Comment: @mauve  i just need to have the X value on the y axes, thats why in plt.scatter() they are swapped

Comment: What happens when you put y in the plot? `plt.plot(y, plotList[index].line, 'r', label="Regression Line", antialiased=True)`?

Comment: @DavidG i edited the main post

Comment: I still don't understand why you're not swapping it for both if that's how you want it.

Comment: You should make your data available, or even better make up some fake data so that your code is a [mcve].  I suspect, as @mauve mentioned, that the problem is that you are *not plotting apples against apples* when you swap x and y in one place and not the other. But without us understanding what x and y *are* we can't tell.

Comment: @Ajean Edit 2 with a .csv file with data

Comment: I appreciate your responsiveness! But it's still not complete - for this example I think you meant to put `line` where `plotList[index]` is. But regardless, I now believe that what is happening is that you really have to do the swap (i.e. `plot(line, X)`), but the values of X are not *sorted*, so the line is going all over the place. Instead of `line = slope * X + intercept`, just make a linear array for X and plot that (`line = slope * np.linspace(0,60) + intercept` then `plot(line, np.linspace(0,60))`. Does that fix it?

Comment: @Ajean i tried your code (pasted and copied) and now it plot a single line, really short and completely wrong for a regression line. My X should be fine , its a np.array like this [ va1 val2 val3 ... ]. Im editing again the code, you were right about that :D

Comment: Ahhh, I see the problem - you have done the regression on "x vs y" not "y vs x", but then you construct the line with x as the independent variable when it should really be y. I will write up an answer.

Comment: @Ajean i have made a test with SOFA statistics, and the results is exactly the same as mine.. BUT with the regression line that go till the end. This means that the regression is correct, but for some reasons the line is being cut. I cannot post other pics  :(

Comment: Note that if your X and Y values just happen to lie on the same range, the results will *look* correct, but they won't be.  Notice that your red line above goes from 0 and stops just past 60. That because of that one dot that at the top of the plot just past 60 (in the y-axis, which is X!).  Trust me, whenever it has looked right it's been by accident, if you're using this code.

Comment: Also, because you seem to have miscontrued me - there is nothing wrong with the regression. The place that is wrong is when you *make the line from the regression results*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your regression has fit a line to X as a function of Y, not Y as a function of X, so when you construct your line you should use Y as the independent variable instead of X. Because neither X nor Y are sorted, it's also probably a good idea to plot a line versus a regularly-sampled array.  I actually might suggest, to avoid all this confusion, doing things normally and just swapping the columns you get X and Y from.

From your csv file, I believe this code produces your desired plot (minus the axis labels).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\smith\Downloads\orders.csv')
Data=df.values
X=Data[:,1]
y=Data[:,0]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err=stats.linregress(y,X)
yvals = np.linspace(y.min(),y.max())
line = slope * yvals + intercept # This is the critical change
plt.scatter(y, X, marker='o',color='#33ffe6',alpha=1,edgecolors='black',linewidths=0.5)
#### Plot
plt.plot(yvals, line, 'r', label="Regression Line", antialiased=True)
#### scala
plt.xlim(y.min()-((y.max() / float(100)) * 5), y.max() + (y.max() / float(100)) * 5)
plt.ylim(X.min()-((X.max() / float(100)) * 5), X.max() + (X.max() / float(100)) * 5)
#### Legenda
plt.legend(loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.07), fancybox=True, shadow=True)
```

[image: correct regression plot]

Comment: this works, and its indeed the right answer. The code is part of a bigger project where i do other things with the same column of Data, this is the reason for the misleading names (x instead of y and vice versa  :) )... I still dont fully understand why i need to use np.linspace() but this is what make the difference. Thank you

Comment: Well, you don't have to use linspace ... I just think it's cleaner (personal preference :) ). So, that part is optional.  Actually all you really need are the endpoints so you could just do a two-point line, that would work also.